# Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget in my app and dont know what is wrong

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I dont know why Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget error is showing while using a column widget . Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a SizedBox widget.

And code is:-

```dart
    class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            const ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                child: Icon(Icons.person),
              ),
              title: Text('Welcome Username!'),
              subtitle: Text('Have a nice day'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            
            const TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            FirstListView(),
            const Text('Some Links'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SomeWidget(),
            const Text('some Places'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            SomeWidget(),
            
            const Text('Recent Searches'),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            SomeWidget(),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 80,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The screenshot of error image is attached
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG6ic.jpg)

Comment: Are you using Expanded in any of your inner widgets?

Comment: Yes i am using Expanded widget in one of the inner widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `shrinkWrap: true` to the inner ListView (`FirstListView`) like:

```
 ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                SomeInnerWidget(),
                SomeInnerWidget2(),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is using ListView inside `SingleChildScrollView`, You can use `shrinkWrap: true,` instead of `Expanded` on this case but you can just use Column widget here like

```dart
const SizedBox(
  height: 10,
),

Column(
  children: [
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
       Text("List item $i")],
),

const Text('Some Links'),
```